# Apache .htaccess not executing a properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I referred to various sites and even many stackoverflow questions, but I am unable to find any solution to this. I have a `.htaccess` file in `/var/www/html/mail/` directory. I also have a file named `sample.php`. I want extensions to get removed. But my rewrite rule in `.htaccess` file is not working. It is neither giving any error. But I can surely say that the file is executing. I tried putting some random text in it. It returned a internal server error. I am not sure what exactly the error is. I also changed the `AllowOverride` in `apache2.conf` to all. My `.htaccess` code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I am following this tutorial https://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/

Any help is acceptable. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you enable mod_rewrite? Run `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and then restart Apache `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Comment: Yes, when I run sudo a2enmod rewrite, already enabled is returned

Comment: I am not sure why. None of rewrite rules are working I guess

Comment: Did you restart apache? If that doesn't work, then it is probably a human error. Check if you have done any other mistakes in implementing that. If you are still stuck, then wait for other people to help you.

Comment: Yes, I have restarted apache server but its not working. thanks for the help

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What error do you get when you type example.com/mail/file ?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am getting a 404 not found error for that. But if I go to link /example.com/mail/file.php I am getting the correct file.